# How would i append the text file into my contenteditable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. Process only .txt files
2. Format if not properly formatted (apple-tab-span must be converted into `&nbsp;` if possible)
3. Append to my contenteditable div

I know no.2 is way far from this question, just tell me how would i process something like it. I've already finished the IDE-like system and im about to add the **Open** and Save functions.

```
$('#open').addEventListener('change', getTextFile, false);

function getTextFile (e) {
     var files = e.target.files;
     var file = files[0];           
     var reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onload = function() {
     console.log(this.result);            
     }
     reader.readAsText(file)
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3veCE/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vinodlouis/88vtR/3/)

```
function readSingleFile(evt) {

var f = evt.target.files[0];
  console.log(f);
   if (!f) {
    alert("Failed to load file");
       return;
} 
if (f.name.indexOf('.txt') == -1) {
        alert(f.name + " is not a valid text file.");
         return;     
              }    

  var r = new FileReader();
  r.onload = function(e) { 
      var contents = e.target.result;
    alert( "Got the file.n" 
          +"name: " + f.name + "n"
          +"type: " + f.type + "n"
          +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
          + "contents: " + contents
    );
      document.getElementById('board').innerHTML = contents;
  }
  r.readAsText(f);
   }

 document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
```

Comment: hey you can use var s = e.target.result.split("\n"); here s will be be line by line array of file

Comment: ok, so there is no library function that will format the fetched text?

Comment: it's javascript manipulation only motto is to converts "\n" and "\r" to respective html keywords i have updated the fiddle you can see it

Comment: it doesnt work when i tried to open the textfile more than once, y?

Comment: it works when you open the file once, but when i tried to open a text file again, it failed, i need to refresh the page

Comment: really? i do not see that issue with the fiddle i just tried to open files again